# logging to all requests

Tags: node.js, express

i have a problem with the logging, but i dont have a clue how to stop it, i just want it to log for the view file and not for static files..

this is my code:

```
//logger.
app.use(function(request, response, next)
{
    if(app.get('env') == 'development')
    {
        console.log('%s %s', request.method, request.url);
        console.log('connection from: ' + request.ip);
    }

    var file = request.url.slice(1 + request.url.indexOf('/'));

    app.get(request.url, function(request, response)
    {
        response.render(file,
        {
            //Var to be named in the render : value;
            'Title': Title,
            'result': result
        });
    });

    next();
});


//Set directory for static files (css, js, img)
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

when i get into the console to see the results. i get this

```
GET /css/bootstrap.css
connection from: 127.0.0.1
GET /css/cover.css
connection from: 127.0.0.1
GET /index
connection from: 127.0.0.1
GET /css/cover.css
connection from: 127.0.0.1
GET /css/bootstrap.css
connection from: 127.0.0.1
```

i just want it to log `GET /index` and not the rest.

Comment: Did you try req.path?

Comment: @neolivz4ever it would be the same. i just want to know if express has a different way to get only the requested view because i need to log the connection once. not logging every request

Comment: You can check public in path to determine if it is static or not.

Answer (score 4):

if you're using express.js, just use logging middleware such as 'morgan' and let express handles the logging for you.  For example the following code will print some logging automatically:

```
var express = require('express');
var morgan = require('morgan');  // Logging middleware
var app = express();

app.use(morgan('dev'));  // 'dev', 'short', 'tiny'. or no argument (default)
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('hello world');
});
app.listen(3000);
```

When you hit localhost:3000, you'll see the logging from express as (in color too):

GET / 200 3ms - 11b

Comment: Link to morgan: https://www.npmjs.org/package/morgan DOCS have some helpful like using the `app.user(morgan(':method :url'));` to get exactly the format nosthertus wanted to see.